# Fail2ban: get mac addresses no ip

Tags: centos, iptables, fail2ban

Is it possible to detect with a fail2ban regex, a MAC address ?

### What I can do: Detect the source ip address

**From the log file**

```
Jan 18 11:15:14 server kernel: [DROP]IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=4.5.6.7 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=239
```

**Fail2ban failregex**

```
failregex = \[DROP\]IN=.* OUT= MAC=.* SRC=<HOST>*
```

Give `1.2.3.4` as a result. Then, any fail2ban `action` can use the `<ip>` variable.

### What I would like to do: Detect the MAC address

Is it possible to do something like that?

```
failregex = \[DROP\]IN=.* OUT= MAC=<MAC> *
```

Shoud give `00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00` as a result. Then, any fail2ban `action` could use a`<mac>` variable for exemple.

Is someone have an answer, or any documentation? I didn't find informations about fail2ban regex or detection possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it on Fail2Ban config and I don't have one to test right now. I did a little bash script to test this and maybe you can extract from here the regex.

```
#!/bin/bash

str="Jan 18 11:15:14 server kernel: [DROP]IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=4.5.6.7 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=239"

[[ ${str} =~ \[DROP\].*MAC=([0-9:]+) ]] && test_output="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

echo $test_output
```

It gives as output: `00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00`

I'm capturing the mac inside a group (between parenthesis) and asigning it to a var. Maybe could be like your `<MAC>`.

I can't assure this because as I said, I don't have fail2ban right now to test, so is a "wild thing"... but I can venture to suggest something like this:

`failregex = \[DROP\].*MAC=<MAC>`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From [fail2ban manual website](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters):

> As a convenience, you can use the predefined entity  in your regexes.  is an alias for (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P\S+), which matches either a hostname or an IPv4 address (possibly embedded in an IPv6 address).

I understand that it is possible use custom regex, but how? There isn't lot of articles about that..